Error "There was an error reconnecting to the Chrome DevTools protocol" when running Cypress tests in a Jenkins pipeline
I'm encountering an issue with my Jenkins pipeline when running Cypress tests. The pipeline fails with the following error:
`Start generate report process
Read and merge jsons from "C:\jenkins\workspace\Shuttle-Online-UITests-Pipeline\cypress\reports\.jsons"
There was an error reconnecting to the Chrome DevTools protocol. Please restart the browser.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:55047
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)`

Here is the context:
The Jenkins pipeline uses a Windows VM as an agent.
In one stage of the pipeline, I execute the following command within a bat block:
`npx cypress run --headed --spec "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts" --env shuttle_webservice=https://xxxxxx/OnlineUITestsMaster.WebService/,version=5.7.0,think_time=1000,lang=en_US --reporter-options "configFile=cypress/config/reporter-chrome-config.js" --browser chrome`

The command is supposed to run Cypress with Chrome in headed mode to execute the specified end-to-end tests.
Additional details:
Cypress version: 13.6.3
Node.js version: 18.15.0
Jenkins version: 2.452.1
Agent operating system: Windows Windows 10
I would appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance!
Restarting the browser and the VM.
